# .NET MVC Routing - bind 2 routeMap parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I need to parse an url like the following

```
/controller/action/subaction/id
```

At the moment i'm using a switch on subaction to see what actually needs to be done. EG:

```
    public ActionResult Members(string subaction, long id=0)
    {
        switch (subaction)
        {
            case "Details":
                var member = _payment.GetMember(id);
                return View("Members_details", member);
            default:
                var members = _payment.GetMembers().ToList();
                return View("Members_list", members);
        }
    }
```

This works, but i'd rather have seperate actions for each event, directly accessed from the route. If possible I would like to combine the action and subaction in the routemap to access the right action.

- /controller/action/ would call action()
- /controller/action/subaction would call action_subaction()
- /controller/action/subaction/id would call action_subaction(id)

Is that possible directly from the routemap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Custom action method selector class

If I were you I'd write an **action method selector** and use that to avoid branching in your actions. I've written one that separates actions that take optional parameters (thus avoiding branched code within action - simplified unit testing). Default Asp.net MVC defined route has an optional `id` parameter

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
id = UrlParameter.Optional
```

So it makes sense to have these two action methods:

```
public ActionResult Index() { ... }
public ActionResult Index(int id) { ... }
```

I've accomplished just that by writing a custom action selector filter. Here's a [detailed blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/improving-aspnet-mvc-maintainability.html) that describes the whole thing and provides some code you can peek at.

### How about a solution for your problem

In your case this means you'd have to write a custom action method selector class called `SubactionAttribute` and then simply decorate your actions with it:

```
[Subaction("Details")]
public ActionResult Members(long id)
{
    var member = _payment.GetMember(id);
    return View("Members.Details", member);
}

[Subaction] // no name would mean default subaction (when not provided)
public ActionResult Members()
{
    var members = _payment.GetMembers().ToList();
    return View("Members.List", members);
}
```

I'm not going to write the whole class for you, but I will only point you in the right direction so you can follow the same path to get where you're headed:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class SubactionAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets subaction name.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SubactionAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public SubactionAttribute()
        : this(null)
    {
        // does nothing
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SubactionAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="subactionName">Sub-action name</param>
    public SubactionAttribute(string subactionName)
    {
        this.Name = subactionName;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ActionMethodSelectorAttribute implementation

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the action method selection is valid for the specified controller context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controllerContext">The controller context.</param>
    /// <param name="methodInfo">Information about the action method.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the action method selection is valid for the specified controller context; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        }

        // get the value of subaction here
        string subName = /* this part you'll have to write */

        // determine whether subaction matches
        return this.Name == subName;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Didnt think of doing it this way, but its exactly what I need.

Comment: I thought it was the perfect awnser, but when implementing I found a flaw you also discuss in the comments of the blog: It doesnt account for duplicates. Meaning Subaction("details") and Subaction("edit") that both take the ID parameter will fail.

Comment: @Hugo: That's not a problem actually. Name those actions differently and then use `[ActionName("SameName")]` attribute on them so they will share the same name on the request level.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you effectively want to use multiple "Details" actions in the same controller? If this is the case then I think this is a good reason to start splitting your controllers.

You should probably start with a Controller called Members with Actions Details and List (or Index)

```
/Members/Details/ID
/Members/List/
```

Do you have a good logical reason to have them all in the same controller?

Alternatively, you could called you Actions MemberDetails and MemberList and URL like...

```
/Controller/MemberDetails/ID
/Controller/MemberList/
```

Give it a go code:

```
[ActionName("Member/Details")]
public ActionResult Members_Details(int id){
    return View();
}
```

Comment: The controller is a sort of module in the project. One project can have like 30 modules. This means I have 30 controllers already the current way. Creating a controller for every action (say 5 per module/controller) would result in 150 controllers. Plus different controllers can have the same action which would result in unwanted naming of controllers and URL

Comment: So then go for my alternative sample. Basically, with MVC, you have a controller level and an Action level - there is no further level such as SubAction

I have no idea if the following will work but try adding this attribute to your action and see what happens (its a long shot thou)...

[See edited answer!]

Comment: @musefan: This surely won't work because route is sliced on slashes.